# EasyB stories invoked by TestNG?

Tags: tdd, bdd, testng, easyb

just wondering if it's possible or if anyone has tried integrating Easyb (BDD) with TestNG in a Maven project. Basically I need to call the **Easyb** stories from the testng.xml or having something that makes call TestNG tests and Easyb stories alternatively in a test regression suite.

I was also thinking that maybe it's achievable having some configurations in my POM file.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any TestNG experience, but as I understand it integrates with JUnit. Couldn't you use the easyb unit test integration: http://code.google.com/p/easyb/wiki/UsingEasybWithJUnit